# How to show compass on google map api v3?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

How to work with UiSettings in Google Map API v3? I try to show compass in map (not street view). I'm new in there if anyone know how to show it will be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is available in Google Maps Android API. Unfortunately, Google Maps Api v3 does not have this yet. I suggest that you file a **feature request** in **Google Issue Tracker**. If you are not familiar with issue tracker:

*Issue Tracker is a tool used internally at Google to track bugs and feature requests during product development. It is available outside of Google for use by external public and partner users who need to collaborate with Google teams on specific projects.*

*Issue Tracker is not a general purpose issue-tracking tool and is not offered as a consumer product for external teams who want to use it for their own issue tracking. You cannot use this tool as a general place to submit feedback on Google products. Please refer to the documentation for individual products for instructions on providing feedback.*

You may visit the issue tracker [here](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/).